# generator object result when converting tuple of string to tuple of int

Tags: python, csv, integer, tuples

I have a .csv file which contains x/y coordinates amongst other information.

I need to extract the x/y coordinate information to feed into another package. That package accepts a list of tuples, of which the tuples contains integers) Eg. [(1,2), (3,4)]

```
rdpList = []
with open ('test.csv', 'rb') as fp_in
    reader = csv.reader(fp_in, delimiter = ',')
    for row in reader:
        del row[0:4] #trimmming to column with x coordinates
        del row[2:] #trimming to column with y coordinate
        rdpList.append(tuple(row))
```

This get me close the result I need, however the data type inside the tuples are string. Eg [('1','2'),('3','4')]

Trying

```
rdpList = []
with open ('test.csv', 'rb') as fp_in
    reader = csv.reader(fp_in, delimiter = ',')
    for row in reader:
        del row[0:4]
        del row[2:]
        rdpList.append(tuple(int(x) for x in tup) for tup in row)
```

gives me

```
[<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f36452e1a00>, <generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f36452e1a50>]
```

Trying

```
rdpList = []
with open ('test.csv', 'rb') as fp_in
    reader = csv.reader(fp_in, delimiter = ',')
    for row in reader:
        del row[0:4]
        del row[2:]
        for y in row:
            int(y)
        rdpList.append(tuple(row))
```

gives me

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'x'
```

Trying

```
rdpList = []
with open ('test.csv', 'rb') as fp_in
    reader = csv.reader(fp_in, delimiter = ',')
    for row in reader:
        del row[0:4]
        del row[2:]
        rdpList.append(tuple(map(int, row.split(','))))
```

gives me

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'
```

How could I get to the result I want? The state of the .csv file is unimportant, only rdpList[] is important,

Comment: Why are you splitting `row`? It's already a list. That's not what I've written in my answer.

Comment: Is this your first time using python? I'd recommend reading a tutorial first before doing anything more.

Comment: I thought so, but I saw some suggestions online and tried it.

Comment: I had assumed the purpose of you asking a question would be to want to take the help of the answers given to you. Guess I was mistaken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your example, it looks like the coordinates are in the 5th and 6th columns.  Assuming a file like:

```
a,b,c,d,1,2,e,f
a,b,c,d,3,4,e,f
a,b,c,d,5,6,e,f
```

This is all you need:

```
import csv

with open ('test.csv', 'rb') as fp_in:
    reader = csv.reader(fp_in)
    rdpList = [(int(row[4]),int(row[5])) for row in reader]

print rdpList
```

Output:

```
[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
```